# Selenium WebDriver Java Cycle of adding words in the same field

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is my first message and it can looks like newbie, but I need your help)
My objective is to add pairs of words from some list, click on Add button, then repeat action with another pair of words. So I created method, which receives 2 words, add them to fields and presses add button.

```
public static void addWord(String eng, String rus) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder, 'English Word')]")).sendKeys(eng);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder, 'Russian Word')]")).sendKeys(rus);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'add')]")).submit();
}
```

So if I do it manually by using `addWord("Hello", "Привет");` it works, but I have a big list of words and want to write code, which will get pair of words from list and add them to method, then repeat until all words will be added. Please advice me how it can be done, maybe using arrays and cycles, but I don't know how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Map with the key pairs and then iterate trough it:

```
Map<String, String> yourMap = new HashMap<String, String>() 
{
  {
    put("Hello", "Привет");
    put("Hello 2", "Привет 2");
    // Add all the inputs needed
  }
};

public static void addWord(Map yourMap) {
  yourMap.forEach((eng, rus) -> {
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder, 'English Word')]")).sendKeys(eng);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder, 'Russian Word')]")).sendKeys(rus);
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class, 'add')]")).submit();
  });
}
```